# Spring boot message_<locale>.properties not read

Tags: java, spring-boot, internationalization

In my spring boot application, I have `message_en_US.properties`, under `main/resources`. This is being read when I run my app from eclipse. But once I build the app and ran the jar using the below command the `message_en_US.properties` is not being read.

```
java -jar my_springboot_proj.jar
```

Below is the config of my `MessageSourceAccessor` initialization,

```
@Bean
public MessageSourceAccessor messageSource()
{
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource aMessageSrc = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    // all files under the classpath with prefix messages
    aMessageSrc.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    return new MessageSourceAccessor(aMessageSrc);
}
```

And to get the message, I do it like,

```
messageSrcAccessor.getMessage(key);
```

I build the jar using,

```
./gradlew build
```

As I unzip the Jar and see, the `message*.properties` that I have are under,

```
BOOT-INF/classes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the problem was the case of the file name. The file name is expected to be in lower case. like `messages_en_us.properties`.